# Spritesheet cut to individual frames

Tags: javascript, animation

I need a hoverable transparent animation for a website, so that it glows when the mouse is over it. I could use two gifs or svgs one on top of another, but (as far as I know) there's no control of the current frame so I tried spritesheets with JavaScript and an if/else inside of every image in order to show the hovered, glowing version or the non-glowing depending on the users's mouse position.

However, there is yet another thing I tried: instead of a single spritesheet, why not cut it and put it all in the same position within a container div? They all start in display:none and they appear at the rate JavaScript tells them to. It works quite nicely. Here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="animation">
        <img src="frame1.png">
        <img src="frame1glow.png">
        <img src="frame2.png">
        <img src="frame2glow.png">
    </div>
```

There are many more frames, of course. This is the JavaScript controller (for two frames):

```
var animation_hovered = false;

animation.onmouseover = function(){animation_hovered = true;}
animation.onmouseout = function(){animation_hovered = false;}

window.setInterval(function(){
  if(animation_hovered == false){
  document.querySelector('#animation img:nth-child(1)').style.display = "initial";
  document.querySelector('#animation img:nth-child(4)').style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector('#animation img:nth-child(3)').style.display = "none";
  }
else{
  document.querySelector('#animation img:nth-child(2)').style.display = "initial";
  document.querySelector('#animation img:nth-child(4)').style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector('#animation img:nth-child(3)').style.display = "none";
  }
window.setTimeout(function(){
  if(animation_hovered == false){
    document.querySelector('#animation img:nth-child(3)').style.display = "initial";
    document.querySelector('#animation img:nth-child(1)').style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector('#animation img:nth-child(2)').style.display = "none";
    }
  else{
    document.querySelector('#animation img:nth-child(4)').style.display = "initial";
    document.querySelector('#animation img:nth-child(1)').style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector('#animation img:nth-child(2)').style.display = "none";        
   }
  }, 300);
}, 600);
```

It seems bulky, but this approach gives you absolute control over your frames and it works nicely. Also, by not using a spritesheet, you can keep your layout pretty simple (or at least a big spritesheet seems to me a bit difficult to hide in my web interface; cut it seems simpler).

Does anyone think I am doing something wrong or could be enhanced in any way?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, I hope you get some great answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this kind of manipulation is done using CSS. E.g. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps

Nevertheless, let's see what can be improved:

**Instead of nth-child selectors, use classes instead**

It provides some meaning to the images, and you can replace the `src` easily afterwards:

```
<div id='animation'>
    <img class='first-frame' src='...'>
    <img class='first-frame-glow' src='...'>
    <img class='second-frame' src='...'>
    <img class='second-frame-glow' src='...'>     
</div>
```

**Refactor the code into a general function that handles the styling**

```
var style_switcher = function(first, second, third) {
    document.querySelector(first).style.display = "initial";
    document.querySelector(second).style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(third).style.display = "none";
};
```

**Use named constants**

```
var TIMEOUT = 300;
var INTERVAL = 600;
```

This will make things easier when you want to change the values.

**Put everything together**

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    if(animation_hovered == false){
        style_switcher('.first-frame', '.second-frame-glow', '.second-frame');
    }else{
        style_switcher('.first-frame-glow', '.second-frame-glow', '.second-frame');
    }
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        if(animation_hovered == false){
            style_switcher('.second-frame', '.first-frame', '.first-frame-glow');
        }else{
            style_switcher('.second-frame-glow', '.first-frame', '.first-frame-glow');
        }
    }, TIMEOUT);
}, INTERVAL);
```

If there is more common behavior, you can abstract that into a function.

Good luck!

Comment: To add more context to your post, instead of just saying *what* you should do, say *why* you should do it.

Comment: Actually I can do it with pure CSS, I just realized. Anyway, I learned a lot. Thank you all!